# Cant get React native app to navigate to homescreen after facebook login

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-fbsdk, react-navigation-stack

I am making a react native application where the user logs in with Facebook and then goes to their home page with more details of the app and I can not get the App to navigate to the homepage after successful login with Facebook.

I'm using React Navigator. I have been searching Stackoverflow for 3 days with no luck...

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

[image]

the homepage successfully navigated when using the regular button
as shown above but it will not after the facebook authentication

```js
//index.js

import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Button,
  Slider,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';
import FBLoginButton from '../FBLoginButton';
import {
  SliderBox
} from 'react-native-image-slider-box';
import {
  SafeAreaView
} from 'react-navigation';
import A from 'react-native-a'
import {
  NavigationActions,
  StackActions
} from 'react-navigation';
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer
} from 'react-navigation';
//import App from '../App';
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  LoginManager,
} = FBSDK;

let isLoggedIn = false



type Props = {};
export default class Login extends Component < Props > {


  constructor(props) {
    //this._loginAuth = this._loginAuth.bind(this)

    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: [
        'https://hluhluwegamereserve.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/IMG_1579.jpg',
        'https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2019/04/26/09/giraffe.jpg',


      ]
    };


  }

  //this.props.navigation.push('Home')


  render() {
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile']).then(
      function(result) {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          alert('Login was cancelled');
        } else {
          alert('Login was successful with permissions: ' + result.grantedPermissions.toString());
          //this.props.navigation.push('Home')
          //this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")

          //this._loginAuth()
        }
      },
      function(error) {
        alert('Login failed with error: ' + error);
      }
    );


    //alert(this.state.loggedIn)


    return (


      <
      View style = {
        styles.container
      } >

      <
      SliderBox style = {
        styles.slider
      }
      images = {
        this.state.images
      }
      sliderBoxHeight = {
        '100%'
      }
      paginationBoxVerticalPadding = {
        0
      }
      //parentWidth={400}

      />

      <
      Button onPress = {
        () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
      }
      title = "Go to Home"
      color = "#841584" /
      >


      <
      FBLoginButton onload = {
        () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
      }
      style = {
        styles.welcome
      } >

      <
      /FBLoginButton>

      <
      Text style = {
        styles.instructions
      } >

      <
      /Text>

      <
      /View>


    );
  }
}
if (this.isLoggedIn) {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
}


// ...

// Attempt a login using the Facebook login dialog,
// asking for default permissions.



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    //padding: 40,
    //marginBottom: 250,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    //marginTop: '15%',
    paddingTop: '15%',
    paddingBottom: '15%',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
  slider: {
    //width: '100%',
    //alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    //width: this.deviceWidth,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginBottom: '10%',
    padding: '5%',
    //paddingTop: 40,
  },
  terms: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'blue',
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 1,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    //marginBottom: 5,
  },
  safeArea: {
    backgroundColor: '#ddd'
  },
});
```

Here is my App.Js

```js
//App.js

/*
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Button,
  Slider,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';
import A from 'react-native-a'
import {
  NavigationActions,
  StackActions
} from 'react-navigation';
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer
} from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import {
  StackNavigator
} from "react-navigation";
import FBLoginButton from './FBLoginButton'




type Props = {};
//Login Screen
const NavigationApp = createStackNavigator({
  Login: Login,
  Home: HomeScreen

}, {
  initialRouteName: "Login"
});

class App extends Component < Props > {

  constructor(props) {


    super(props);

  }


  render() {

    return (
      //Empty View For App.js
      <
      View >
      <
      /View>


    );
  }
}

//Navagation Goes To Login.js For Default


export default createAppContainer(NavigationApp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```js
FBLogout = (accessToken) => {
  let logout =
      new GraphRequest(
          "me/permissions/",
          {
              accessToken: accessToken,
              httpMethod: 'DELETE'
          },
          (error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                  console.log('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
              } else {
                  LoginManager.logOut();
              }
          });
  new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(logout).start();
  };
```

and added a button and used

LoginManager.logout();

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
  <SettingsView profile={this.state.profile}/>
  <Button
    onPress={() => {
      FBLogout();
      this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
    }}
    title="Log Out"
    color="#3b5998"
  />
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing an if-statement in your code outside of your class, do this one:

1. Once you are logged-in, Facebook's LoginManager will be returning a `Promise`
2. The promise will then be checked. So, if you have

```
.then((result) => {
   if(result) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
   } else {
      alert('...'); // Anything you want to do if login failed.
   }
});
```